# Tensorflow MNIST: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Network on Tensorflow, using their default MNIST data set.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)


def compute_accuracy(v_xs, v_ys):
    global prediction
    y_pre = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, keep_prob: 1})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pre,1), tf.argmax(v_ys,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, ys: v_ys, keep_prob: 1})
    return result

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    # stride [1, x_movement, y_movement, 1]
    # Must have strides[0] = strides[3] = 1
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    # stride [1, x_movement, y_movement, 1]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# define placeholder for inputs to network
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) # 28x28
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_image = tf.reshape(xs, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
# print(x_image.shape)  # [n_samples, 28,28,1]

## conv1 layer ##
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5, 1,32]) # patch 5x5, in size 1, out size 32
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1) # output size 28x28x32
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)                                         # output size 14x14x32

## conv2 layer ##
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5, 32, 64]) # patch 5x5, in size 32, out size 64
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2) # output size 14x14x64
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)                                         # output size 7x7x64

## fc1 layer ##
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
# [n_samples, 7, 7, 64] ->> [n_samples, 7*7*64]
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

## fc2 layer ##
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

# the error between prediction and real data
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys * tf.log(prediction),
                                              reduction_indices=[1]))       # loss
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


for i in range(100):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(10)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs: batch_xs, ys: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(compute_accuracy(
        mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels))
```

On executing, python crashes with this message:
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc

I was able to point out that this happens when I call the `compute_accuracy` function, or in general, when I load the whole mnist.test iamges and labels.
Any suggestions on what can be done, given I wish to use this data. I have been able to work with images as a whole, in a different case.

Comment: Activations for the first conv layer take 2GB of RAM for 10k batch, see analysis [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6019#issuecomment-267881864). Solution for smaller memory is to do something like [eval_in_batches](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6431560b7ec3565154cb9cdc9c827db78ccfebe7/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L265)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by reducing the number of test images to compute accuracy, e.g. I replaced

```
print(compute_accuracy(mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels))
```

With something similar to

```
batch_test = mnist.test.next_batch(5000)
print(compute_accuracy(batch_test[0], batch_test[1])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am running tensorflow on cpu, that is the solution.

Answer (score 12):

I think you're running out of memory. It runs okay on my machine (6GB graphics card). Try decreasing the batch size, or using a smaller fully connected layer.