# x exceeds 10% of free system memory, even though plenty is available

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

Every time i try to run `model.predict()` it throws an error if the picture is too large (which is fine) but the error says that `tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 3717120800 exceeds 10% of system memory` Yeah it does, i have 32GB, but why can't it use, say 20% or maybe 30% (btw, cuda is disabled for theese test, since my GPU only has 6GB)
BTW: I know this is a warning and not an error, but the program crashes a few moments later, and gives me no other output ;(

Here's the model:

```
def build_dce_net():
    input_img = keras.Input(shape=[None, None, 3])
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(
        32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(input_img)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(
        64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(conv1)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(
        96, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(conv2)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(
        96, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(conv3)
    int_con1 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv4, conv3])
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(
        64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(int_con1)
    int_con2 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv5, conv2])
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(
        32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", padding="same"
    )(int_con2)
    int_con3 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv6, conv1])
    x_r = layers.Conv2D(24, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation="tanh", padding="same")(
        int_con3
    )
    #return keras.models.load_model('./high-res-trained')
    return keras.Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x_r)
```

And yes, everything is normally indented, but still can't get that working on stackoverflow

Edit: After running the model on ubuntu, i get a way more useful log:

```
2022-05-31 13:41:27.744568: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 9663676416 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2022-05-31 13:41:29.461537: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 14495514624 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Comment: That is not an error, only a warning.

Comment: Problem is, program crashes a few moments later, without any error codes what so ever. This is litterally the only output i got

Comment: You should include the full log in the question, not your interpretation of it.

Comment: Well, there's no more of the log. That IS the log. That pesky one line repeating 3 times. I can't find any more info generated on it

Comment: Again, I am not interested in your interpretation, only on the raw information.

Comment: I simply misunderstood what you wrote. The post has been updated with the single log output i have

Comment: So it is trying to allocate around 24 GB of memory, you probably do not have enough for that, consider using less memory.

Comment: these answers might help. the error implies you are running out of RAM https://stackoverflow.com/q/41314316/5666087 https://stackoverflow.com/q/58647973/5666087

Comment: But what i don't understand is, i have 32GB. and ubuntu only use 3, leaving 29GB untouched. Monitoring with htop, shows i only ever get to 18GB before a crash.

Comment: 18 + 24 > 32, simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having the same problem. I setup a swap memory in my linux. Then the problem was solved.